# Event in child view not firing - Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, view, amd

I'm developing a small project in an attempt to learn backbone.js and I'm using AMD (recommended in a tutorial). I have a child view for an "Athlete Control", basically a view I plan to reuse on other pages/views. The click event on the child view (AthleteView) doesn't fire.

The AthleteView is rendered in a div within the TimerView and the TimerView is rendered in a div with id "page" on the index page. I've included everything below, as I suspect it could how I'm setting things up that is the problem.

Main View:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'views/SettingsView',
  'views/AthleteControlView',
  'text!templates/timerTemplate.html',
  'timer'
], function($, _, Backbone, SettingsView, AthleteView, timerTemplate){

  var TimerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#page"),

    render: function(){      
      this.$el.html(timerTemplate);
      var settingsView = new SettingsView();
      settingsView.render();

      var athleteView = new AthleteView();
      athleteView.render();

      console.log('rendered Timer');

    }
  });

  return TimerView;

});
```

Child View:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!templates/AthleteControlTemplate.html',
  'jqueryui'
], function($, _, Backbone, keypadTemplate){

  var AthleteView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $("#AthleteControl"),

    events: {
          'click': 'clickHandler'
    },

    render: function(){
      $("#AthleteControl").html(keypadTemplate);
      console.log('rendered AthleteControl');
    },


    clickHandler: function()
    {
      alert('click');
      console.log('click');
    }

  });

  return AthleteView;

});
```

ROUTER.JS

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'views/TimerView'
], function($, _, Backbone, TimerView) {

  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      '*actions': 'defaultAction'
    }
  });

  var initialize = function(){
    var app_router = new AppRouter;
    app_router.on('route:defaultAction', function (actions) {
        var timerView = new TimerView();
        timerView.render();
    });

    Backbone.history.start();
  };
  return { 
    initialize: initialize
  };
});
```

Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="page">
    Loading....
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

TIMER TEMPLATE:

```
<div class = "Controls">
     <button id="Start">Start</button>
     <button id="Stop">Stop</button>
      <button id="Reset">Reset</button>
 </div>
 <div id="AthleteControl"></div>
```

Comment: Do `#AthleteControl` and `#page` exist when your views are being loaded? Using `el: $(...)` is almost always a bad idea IMO. I think `el: 'some selector string'` is also a bad idea, letting each view create its own `el` and letting the caller put it on the page bypasses all sorts of problems.

Comment: I've included the additional files to demonstrate how things are currently being loaded (apologies if this is overkill). I think both do exist when the views are being loaded but my understanding of this actually works is still lacking. Could you exemplify what you mean by letting each view create its own el etc? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the `id="AthleteControl"` element comes from inside `timerTemplate.html`. That means that `$('#AthleteControl")` won't find anything when this code is executed:

```
var AthleteView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $("#AthleteControl"),
```

That means that `AthleteView` will end up behaving as though you said:

```
var AthleteView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: undefined,
```

If you don't specify a view's `el` explicitly, the view will create an empty `<div>` as the `el`. Things like:

```
el: $("some-selector")
```

are almost always a mistake due to the timing problems. Instead, just use the selector string and let Backbone convert it to a DOM node when it needs to:

```
el: "some-selector"
```

The quick fix should be to un-jQuery the `el`s:

```
el: '#page'

el: '#AthleteControl'
```

---

As far as the "let the views create their own `el`s" is concerned, you let the views create their own DOM nodes to use as their `el` rather than trying to bind views to `el`s that are already on the page. This approach:

1. Makes your views more self-contained.
2. Helps to reduce event binding conflicts as your application gets larger and involves more views.
3. Helps to reduce memory leaks because each view has one DOM node (and vice versa) while the application is running.
4. Removing a view is a simple `view.remove()` call rather than manually cleaning up the event bindings and HTML. If you have subviews then you'd override [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) in your view to call `remove` on the subviews before chaining to the default `remove` implementation.

This approach (without the AMD/require.js stuff for clarity) would look more like the following.

HTML:

```
<script id="timerTemplate" type="text/x-underscore">
    <div class="Controls">
        <button id="Start">Start</button>
        <button id="Stop">Stop</button>
        <button id="Reset">Reset</button>
    </div>
</script>

<div id="page">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var AthleteView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: 'AthleteControl',
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html('Athlete control stuff goes here.');
        return this; // This is standard practice, you'll see why below.
    }
});

var TimerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function () {
        var tmpl = _.template($('#timerTemplate').html());
        this.$el.html(tmpl());

        var athleteView = new AthleteView();
        this.$el.append(athleteView.render().el);
        return this;
    }
});

var timer_view = new TimerView;
$('#page').html(timer_view.render().el);
```

Note the `return this` in the `render` methods and note how `this.$el.html` and `this.$el.append` are used to build and combine the views.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/r4tsA/1/

Comment: Thanks for that comprehensive answer, much appreciated. That fixed the problem alright and i'm starting to get a better understanding. I'd upvote your answer but don't have the requisite rep as yet, but i will as soon as i do. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

To bind an event to an action you need to specify which element is listening to which event, e.g.

```
.., var AthleteView = Backbone.View.extend({
..
events: {
  'click button.btn': 'doSomething'
},
..
doSomething: function(e) {
  // code goes here
},
..
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work. I've added a simple button and did just that but no joy.

Comment: Incorrect. `'click': 'doSomething'` in `events` binds the click event to the view's `el` itself, the documentation even says this: ["Omitting the `selector` causes the event to be bound to the view's root element (`this.el`)."](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents)